# MSAL login Build method causing infinite wait time in Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I am having a Xamarin Forms application that uses a Microsoft AD login, but when I try to fetch the accounts details it is causing an infinite wait loop for getting the PublicClientApplication.Build().
The issue is happening with the creation of IPublicClientApplication object.

```
        private IPublicClientApplication _app;
        private IPublicClientApplication App
        {
            get
            {
                return _app ?? (_app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                    .WithAuthority(Authority)
                    .WithRedirectUri(ReturnUri)
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(ActivityOrWindowFunc)
                    .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(companyname)
                    .Build()); // This call causing the issue
            }
        }
```

Here when I call the build method causing infinite waiting time and I am unable to access my application because I am opening the view based on the response of this App variable(This will fetch accounts in cache and open login page or next page).

I am receiving this message "AppName.iOS[14844:1920113] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7ff783732f60>." and it will wait for a long time.

Anyone, please help me for solving this issue.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've caused a "deadlock", because you have the UI waiting on MSAL, which perhaps is waiting for the ios UI to "release" some resource. Did you do this at app start, so there is not yet a page being displayed? Open the app to a custom "Loading..." page that you make. Once that page is loaded, have it start a **background** thread to call "Build". This avoids blocking the UI. Put a breakpoint, or a debug message, to confirm that "Build" has returned/completed. Once that works, then add code to go to your app's main page.

Comment: MainPage is already displayed with an icon, but after that, I am waiting for this one to get execute and open login/next page based on this response

Comment: ok, that is different. But the error message has nothing to do with Build - sounds like something is wrong with the page you are trying to display. What makes you certain that Build is the problem? As a test, comment out the reference to Build. Instead, set hardcoded values that will work  (Create an App using constant values in your code), and call the next page. Find the cause of that message, and fix it, before trying to get Build to work.